# How to save multi-layer PSD with Python/ImageMagick/Wand

Tags: python, image, imagemagick

I need to save a multi layer PSD using Python. The only solution I found is using ImageMagick, as Python PSD libraries (such as psd-tools and psd-tools3) don't support layers writing.
With ImageMagick the command is:

```
convert ./image1.png ./image2.png ./image3.jpg -clone 0 final.psd
```

but I'm not able to find how to translate such command in Python/Wand code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution with [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) would be something like..

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="./image1.png") as img:
    img.read(filename="./image2.png")
    img.read(filename="./image3.jpg")
    img.read(filename="./image1.png")  # -clone 0
    img.save(filename="final.psd")
```

.. but I"m sure there's cleaner ways.